# Android: SQLite - Correct way to build a cursor with a large array of selection constraints

Tags: android, sql, cursor, mediastore, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to create a `Cursor` from a table, constrained to a certain set of ID's, passed into the `selection` arguments as follows: (simplified for readability)

```
String[] ids; //The id's to constrain the cursor to
StringBuilder selection;

//for each id, add to the selection
for(int i = 0; i < ids.length(); i++) {
    selection = Table.column._ID + " = " + ids[i];
        if(i < ids.length -1) {
            selection.append( "OR" ) //Add an "OR" after each selection (except the last)
        }
}    

Cursor cursor = query(uri, projection, selection.toString(), null, null);
```

The idea is that this `Cursor` will be filled with any item whose id matches an item in the list.

This works ok, except for a huge list, I get an `SQLiteException`, as the argument is too large:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)
```

I understand why this is happening. The query is built as:

```
 selection = Table.column._ID = id[1] OR Table.column._ID = id[2] ...
```

And can get pretty massive.

The question is, how can I make this query work? Surely there is a more efficient way to populate a `Cursor` with a huge list of constraints / selection criteria, right?

Should I be passing the ids into `selectionArgs` and dealing with it that way?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html, try in operator

Comment: Can you explain how and what that might do?

Comment: well this is a simple expression, not 1000 "or" expressions

Comment: OK, I got it to work. I wasn't familiar with the IN expression, but I've got it now. I'll answer my own question in a while. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to pskink for his input. The answer is to use the 'IN' operator.

```
String[] ids; //The id's to constrain the cursor to
StringBuilder selection;

selection = Table.column._ID + " IN (";
for(int i = 0; i < ids.length(); i++) {
    selection.append(ids[i]);
        if(i < ids.length -1) {
            selection.append( "," ) //Add an "," after each selection (except the last)
        }
}
selection.append(")");
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
Selection = "Table.column._ID IN (ids[1], ids[2], ids[3], ...);
```

Which is much better than:

```
Selection = "Table.column._ID = ids[1] OR Table.column._ID = ids[2] OR Table.column._ID = ids[3] ...";
```